# How to find the selected tab using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am implementing tabs using jquery and dont want to use jquery UI. How to find which tab I clicked?

Here is my tabs structure

```
<div class="tabs">
    <!-- Tabs starts -->
    <div class="tabview-content">
        <div class="card-panel-selector">
            <div class="-card-panel-selector-content">
                <div class="card-panel-selection card-panel-current">
                    <div class="panel- label"><span>XYZ</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-panel-selection">
                    <div class="panel-label"><span>ABCD</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-panel-selection card-panel-selection-account">
                    <div class="panel-label"><span>PQRS</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-panel-selection">
                    <div class="panel-label"><span>ASDF</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Hello krishyalla, the [jQueryUI tabs plugin](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) uses one UL list for menu and multiple other divs for holding the tab content (you can inspect it in [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)). Your HTML structure probably won't work. Here is one example how it could look like: http://jsfiddle.net/VcVpM/5/ Try to update the fiddle and your question with your own css, then maybe somebody can help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You would likely want to add some kind of class whenever one of your tabs was clicked and add a `selected` class to that specific tab as seen below :

```
//When a tab is clicked'
$('.tab').click(function(){
     //Remove all existing selections
     $('.tab').removeClass('selected');
     //Select the current tab
     $(this).addClass('selected');

     //Logic to show / hide all the tabs except for the selected ones
});
```

If you took an approach similar to the one above, you could always access the tab that is selected through the following selector :

```
//Grabs the currently selected tab
$('.tab.selected')
```

**Edit : Updated for a more specific answer to OP's situation**

It appears that you are using the class `card-panel-current` to indicate the tab that is selected, so you can modify the above example accordingly :

```
 //Your panel was selected
 $('.card-panel-selection').click(function(){ 
    //Unselect all previous panels
    $('.card-panel-selection').removeClass('card-panel-current'); 
    //Select the current one
    $(this).addClass('card-panel-current');

    //Logic to show/hide contents here
});
```

Grabbing the current tab could be done similar to above as well :

```
$('.card-panel-selection.card-panel-current')
```

or

```
$('.card-panel-current')
```

Comment: @falsetru it din't work...the selected class should be on the card-panel-current right...

Comment: $('.card-panel-selection .selected').click(function(){
      
      $('.card-panel-selection').removeClass('selected');
      
      $(this).addClass('selected');

      
 });